# Marathon: How to specify environment variables in args

Tags: microservices, mesos, marathon, consul

I am trying to run a Consul container on each of my Mesos slave node.

With Marathon I have the following JSON script:

```
{
    "id": "consul-agent",
    "instances": 10,
    "constraints": [["hostname", "UNIQUE"]],
    "container": {
        "type": "DOCKER",
        "docker": {
            "image": "consul",
            "privileged": true,
            "network": "HOST"
        }
    },
    "args": ["agent","-bind","$MESOS_SLAVE_IP","-retry-join","$MESOS_MASTER_IP"]
}
```

However, it seems that marathon treats the `args` as plain text.

That's why I always got errors:

```
==> Starting Consul agent...
==> Error starting agent: Failed to start Consul client: Failed to start lan serf: Failed to create memberlist: Failed to parse advertise address!
```

So I just wonder if there are any workaround so that I can start a Consul container on each of my Mesos slave node.

---

**Update:**

Thanks @janisz for the link.

After taking a look at the following discussions:

- [#3416](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/issues/3416): *args in marathon file does not resolve env variables*
- [#2679](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/issues/2679): *Ability to specify the value of the hostname an app task is running on*
- [#1328](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/issues/1328): *Specify environment variables in the config to be used on each host through REST API*
- [#1828](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/issues/1828): *Support for more variables and variable expansion in app definition*

as well as the Marathon documentation on [Task Environment Variables](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/task-environment-vars.html).

My understanding is that:

- Currently it is not possible to pass environment variables in args
- Some post indicates that one could pass environment variables in `"cmd"`. But those environment variables are Task Environment Variables provided by Marathon, not the environment variables on your host machine.

Please correct if I was wrong.

Comment: I think this question is related to [#3416](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/issues/3416)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
{
    "id": "consul-agent",
    "instances": 10,
    "constraints": [["hostname", "UNIQUE"]],
    "container": {
        "type": "DOCKER",
        "docker": {
            "image": "consul",
            "privileged": true,
            "network": "HOST",
            "parameters": [
                "key": "env",
                "value": "YOUR_ENV_VAR=VALUE"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Or

```
{
    "id": "consul-agent",
    "instances": 10,
    "constraints": [["hostname", "UNIQUE"]],
    "container": {
        "type": "DOCKER",
        "docker": {
            "image": "consul",
            "privileged": true,
            "network": "HOST"
        }
    },
    "env": {
        "ENV_NAME" : "VALUE"
    }
}
```